# Why does my nav bar move slightly when going to the resume tab

Tags: css, nav

http://www.michaelhoffmandesign.com

So I and pretty new to coding and have been coding this website from the ground up for professional use. The problem is, when users click the Resume section, the whole navbar moves over to the left. I have tried to correct this by adding a left:x px. But it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: Post some code here, if the link is dead, your question won't be useful anymore to future visitors, but really nice design for the menu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar causes the slight difference. You can enable scrollbar on all the pages with:

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This makes the scrollbar always visible and only active when needed.

Or another solution would be:

```
html {height: 101%;}
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked! But now my nav's drop shadow is missing in the contact section haha. Fix one problem, and another one pops up.

Answer (score 0):

use margin: 0 auto for nav to align center

Try this:

```
nav {
position: relative;
width: 800px;
height: 17px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html for resume.html, check this line :

> < nav **style="right:10px;"**>

Remove that style attribute and give it a try.